# Visual Studio LoadTest - how to extract the actual execution time to run the 1st step?

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing, msloadtest

I'm trying to run MS Visual Studio Load Test against one of our C# Api hosted in GCP environment.  Think times are set to zero and off.

The order of the Web tests are as below:

1. Ping Query
2. Authenticate User
3. Get UserApplicationContext Query
4. Logout User

[image]

Sometimes, it's very quick.  But, Sometimes, it's taking long time to execute the first web test (Ping Query).   I found out that the more the user loads, the longer the time taken to start the test takes.

I can confirm that **PingQuery** is the very quick request and it should take less than 1 sec to execute... but it's taking **43 secs** as shown in the screenshot.

If I removed the first step (PingQuery) and start from 2nd step (AuthenticateUserCommand), AuthenticateUser Web test takes about 45 seconds to execute.

I tried to play with the users count and the time taken to execute the 1st step is like the following:

- 50 Users - 40-45 sec
- 10 Users - 8-10 sec
- 1 User - 1-2 sec

So, in my opinion, those time taken to execute the 1st webtest is never accurate and it counts time taken to **prepare the test** + **execute the test**.

I would like to know how I can exclude the preparation time before the execution of 1st step.  I don't know which settings I missed.  Could you please help me to record the exact amount of time to execute the 1st step?

Comment: You also need to look at the "Graphs" and "Tables" in the results. What do you mean by "preparation time"? A test duration of 52 seconds is too small to learn anything, I suggest at least 5 minutes (and ideally much longer) so the various systems can settle down. Please list the test parameters. The question states "The order of the Web tests are as below: 1... 2... 3... 4..." but the screenshot only shows one web test and its names is very different to anything in that list.

Comment: that one webtest contains another 4 webtests.  I used it to group the full user scenario